# Returning data in a function and then using the variables?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function called `query_select` using sort of a modified database class. I can get the information from it, and it works, but that's only in the function. Here's the code:

```
public function query_select($query)
{
    try
    {
        $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $this->success = $this->query->execute();
        $result = $this->query->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo $row['id'], '<br>', $row['username'], '<br>', $row['password'];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
    $this->parameters = array();
}
```

So that displays this:

```
1
JoelE
123456
```

And I'm trying to do this:

```
public function query_select($query)
{
    try
    {
        $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $this->success = $this->query->execute();
        $result = $this->query->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
    $this->parameters = array();
}
```

And then try something like this after I called the function in my page file:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo $row['id'], '<br>', $row['username'], '<br>', $row['password'];
}
```

But I get this:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8
```

Comment: Where are you making the function call ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the value returned by the function to a variable first:

```
$result = query_select(...);
foreach($result as $row) {
  echo $row['id'], '<br>', $row['username'], '<br>', $row['password'];
}
```